# If the limit of the sequence exists, find it. If not, prove that the limit does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the following sequence:

$\{[\sqrt{n}][\sqrt{n + 1}-\sqrt{n}]\}$ for $ n \geq 1$.

If the limit exists, find it and prove that the limit is indeed your choice. If not, prove that the limit does not exist.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative answer: Use the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality.

$$\sqrt{(n)(n+1)} - n \leq \frac{n+n+1}{2} -n =\frac{2n+1}{2} -n = \frac{1}{2}$$

And then prove it's an increasing sequence. So since it's bounded above by $\frac{1}{2}$ the sequence is convergent to its supremum.

Then  suppose the supremum of the terms of your sequence, $L$, is less than $\frac{1}{2}$. Clearly $L > 0$ since your sequence is positive (your first term is always larger).

Then that means $\sqrt{n^2+n} -n \leq L$ for all $n$.

So for all $n$,

$$\sqrt{n^2+n} \leq L+n$$
$$n^2+n \leq L^2+n^2 + 2Ln$$
$$(1-2L)n \leq L^2$$
$$n \leq \frac{L^2}{1-2L}$$ since $0\leq L < \frac{1}{2}$.

But $\frac{L^2}{1-2L}$ is finite, so this is a contradiction.

Hence the sequence must converge to its supremum which must be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=\sqrt{n}\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+1}$.

So the limit is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) = n\left( \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} -1 \right) $$
Now use the Binomial theorem.